# Delete a value from table in descending order PHP (Possible?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this table named `accession`:

```
account_number      ||      access_number
    201             ||           10091
    201             ||           10092
    202             ||           10099
    202             ||           10100
    202             ||           10101
    202             ||           10102
```

How to delete 1 value here using `desc`? For example, if I want to delete values: `account_number` 202 and `access_number` 10102, I have this query:

```
$account_number = $_GET['account_number'];

$delvalue = "delete * from accession where account_number='$account_number'";
mysql_query($delvalue) or die('Error Deleting');
```

But all the values of a specific account number are deleted. (of course that will happen)
Could you let me understand some ideas? Thank you..

Comment: Would an `order by` and `limit` clause not work?

Comment: do u have any other field ? such as auto increment id...

Comment: @user1844933: no other id. do i need to have one?

Comment: yes If you have an auto increment id, then you can delete with help of using max id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query if you haave defined unique auto increament id  colomn

```
delete from accession 
where account_number='$account_number'
order by (id) DESC limit 1
```

Comment: `access_number` could be used here in place of `id` and give you a very similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `max`:

```
delete * from accession 
where account_number='$account_number'
and access_number=(select max(access_number) from accession where account_number='$account_number')
```